# Backticks as a syntactic operator

Tags: haskell

Just ran into something that seems strange to me. Backticks function as something like a syntactic operator.

```
applyOp :: Int -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
applyOp x op y = x `op` y

>  applyOp 2 (+) 5
7
```

I was surprised to see this. I had always imagined that backticks were required to surround an operator symbol or identifier, not an identifier which can be bound during execution to an operator. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: Yes, backticks are syntax. They turn any identifier into an infix operator.

Comment: There's really no difference between an identifier bound during pattern matching and an identifier bound via a definition.

Comment: If you really want your mind blown, `let apply x (*) y = x * y in apply 1 (+) 2`

Comment: The scope of the identifier cannot possibly affect whether the identifier can be surrounded with backticks, since parsing happens before scope checking. In general, as far as the parser is concerned, there is no difference between a globally bound identifier or a locally bound identifier (indeed, even an *unbound* identifier is just an identifier to the parser). If you are ever confused about the syntax of Haskell, the best way to resolve that is to consult the [syntax reference](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html#x17-18000010.5)

Comment: You can also write definitions like ``x `op` y = ...``, to define an `op` identifier. And you can give a fixity declaration for a backticked operator: ``infixr 5 `Cons` ``. Almost everything works out exactly as you'd expect. Unfortunately, there's a weird syntactic corner having to do with kind-promotion of these sorts of things. It's a bug that may or may not get fixed.

Comment: When I was learning I was disappointed that I couldn't say ``x `op arg` y``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backticks are syntax sugar that turns an identifier into an infix operator. That is to say, `` a `f` b = f a b `` is the general rewrite rule. This is useful for clarity, but also allows one to avoid too many brackets, since `f (a b) (c d)` can be rewritten as `` a b `f` c d ``.

However there are a few caveats with using these, but only two restrictions:

- **The backticked expression must be an identifier**, so `` 1 `mod` 2 `` is valid, but `` a `zipWith (+)` b `` is not valid, because it involved a function application.
- **Only alphanumeric identifiers can be backticked**, so `` 1 `mod` 2 `` is valid, but `` 1 `(+)` 2 `` is invalid. You could see this as an application of the previous restriction.
- **Backticked expressions have precedence 9, and are left-associative**, so `` a `f` b `f` c `` is parsed as `` (a `f` b) `f` c ``, and in general other operators will inlcude it, so `` a +
  c `f` b `` is parsed as `` a + (c `f` b) ``*

In this case, `` applyOp x op y = x `op` y `` is valid, since `op` is an alphanumeric identifier, and this is equivalent to `applyOp x op y = op x y`. Note that there is *no* restriction on  binding pattern-matched identifiers!

---

**This is untrue for the standard Prelude operators `!!` and `.`. More info of precedence and fixity can be found in [The Haskell 98 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html).*

Comment: Section 3.2 says "An operator is either an operator symbol, such as + or $$, or is an ordinary identifier enclosed in grave accents (backquotes), such as `op`. For example, instead of writing the prefix application op x y, one can write the infix application x \`op\` y." That suggested to me that backticks were considered as something like an extension of the identifier rather than being parsed as an operator. As you say, a backticked expression has a precedence. So there must be some ad hoc processing in the parser. No?.

Comment: @RussAbbott Yes, that is my understanding. The precedence `infixl 9` is the default for *all* infix operators, hence the precedence for backticked identifiers. This is parser-level, you can test this by seeing what errors occur when you write `\`(+)\`` or another illegal expression.

Comment: Minor point: unless you are compiling your code with `-XHaskell98` (or using a non-GHC compiler which doesn't implement Haskell 2010) you should reference the Haskell 2010 report (which is the default semantics used by GHC) - 2010 and '98 are largely identical, but there are some minor differences which can cause some confusion. (The only thing lacking in 2010 which is present in '98 is `n+k` patterns, which are widely considered a mis-feature anyways).

Comment: All three bullet points are wrong. "The backticked expression must be an identifier": there's no such thing as a backticked expression. It's just an identifier (perhaps qualified) between backticks. "Only alphanumeric identifiers can be backticked": there are no other kinds of identifiers. ("An identifier consists of a letter followed by..." – Haskell Report.) `(+)` isn't an identifier, nor is `+`. "Backticked expressions have precedence 9, and are left-associative": they have the fixity they're declared to have, defaulting to infixl 9, like any operator. They're just operators.