# what does ' ' mean in this following haskell code?

Tags: haskell

In the following code there is a taype definition "VarTree" , which is used to build tree . in this tree each occurrence of the constructor Var shall represent as a variable symbol in the tree.(constructor Node makes a normal tree of type a)

we should write a funcrion insert :: [VarTree a] -> VarTree a -> VarTree a
and in this function each occurrence of the constructor Var i must be replaced by the ith (starting at 1) tree in ts.

I saw this following code as sample solution , and i don't know why should we write  at in ' ' and also ts and i in left and right side of it (not direct infront of it)?

```
data VarTree a = Node a [VarTree a] |
deriving Show
insert :: [VarTree a] -> VarTree a -> Var Int
insert ts (Var i) = ts 'at' i
   where
     at (t:ts) 1 = t
     at (t:ts) i =  at ts (i-1)
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611311/backticks-as-a-syntactic-operator) for example. You can put an operator inside *backticks*, also known as backquotes,  (but definitely **not** ordinary single quotes) to change it from prefix to infix. But it is perfectly OK here to just use: `insert ts (Var i) = at ts i`

Comment: It means a syntax error, since `'at'` is not a valid `Char` literal. You've misread  (or someone miswrote) `'` for `\``.

Comment: You can also define `at` this way: ``(t:ts) `at` 1 = t``